# Updating SMS copy within a live Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

I know that to update email copy for an email within a live Journey you need to edit and save that email activity within the Journey.

Is the same true for SMS?

There is no edit functionality from within a live Journey, so I'm wondering if I can just update the SMS copy from within Content Builder and then that saved version is automatically sent from a Journey.

Answer (score 1):

Upon Journey activation, SMS messages are being created in Mobile Connect. In Mobile Connect it is possible to edit the message. This will update the live message content as triggered from the journey. So it is possible to update SMS copy even for an active journey without creating a new version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct there is no edit functionality from within live journey for SMS.

But, just updating the SMS copy withing the journey builder will not get saved in journey builder.

You would need to create a new version of journey and update the SMS or select a new SMS and activate the new version of journey.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible by editing the SMS message in content builder. It will automatically update the SMS in the journey even after it is live.

Comment: Updating the SMS in the content builder won't update the Live journey.